# Reputation change is not showing

Tags: bug

The Reputation change is not showing.

Normally if there is a `+` change, it will show as `+amount` but it is not showing and also, when clicking on the Icon, not showing the rep.

[image]
Browser details

EDGE on Windows 10 (x64)

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"

Chrome on Windows 10 (x64)

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"

### Update

It is found to be fixed.

Comment: I reported the same bug a couple minutes before you did... Sorry...

Comment: _a couple minutes_ ? 1 min dif. my bad typing speed :-)

Comment: we may started at the same time @Mithrandir

Comment: Perhaps, yeah. In any case, i reported it first :P