# Profile not showing reputation correctly for Network accounts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> Not a duplicate of [Reputation change is not showing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293095/) or [Why does the reputation dropdown not show this upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293094/) because it is talking about the achievements updating.

Recently, I and Mithrandir reported a bug that the dropdown menu is not showing reputation changes.

This one is related to it.

The **Communities** section is not showing correct reputation too

[image: communities on other site]

In Meta SE, my reputation has changed to 311 but it is still on 308.

Also in the dropdown menu,

[image: dropdown menu]

In SE for Android too

[image: SE Android app]

#### In short

The reputation is up to date only in the profile -> reputation section and remaining all are broken

Comment: Already retracted.

Comment: meh, maybe not a dupe but i'd bet my big toe on it being the same cause

Comment: anymore of these posts and we might as well have a common tag for it

Answer (score 5):

This is how the list of network accounts has *always* worked. Your reputation only updates immediately *on that specific site* and the rest of the sites are pulled from the network account listing. That list is not updated in real-time, but instead just updates your reputation from all sites on a cycle similar to how badges are awarded. It'll update eventually, just not the moment you receive an upvote.

Comment: Will it take more than one hour?

Comment: I don't know exactly how often it updates, but it has updated at least once since you posted this, so it seems to still be working.

Comment: seems like it is a bug. Still not updated. I think previously I didn't found such a problem. It is already 3 hours passed and still not updated

Comment: I think the issue is with deleted posts, which do not cause a reputation event. Only things like upvote, downvote, acceptance, etc, cause the "network reputation" to be synchronised. So in theory, the rep can be different for weeks, months, and years, for users without lots of activity.
(Again, not sure, just what I remember from comments here and there.)