# Fixing of Reputation system cause another bug

Tags: bug, android-app

The [reputation system bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293106/profile-not-showing-reputation-correctly-for-network-accounts) is found to be fixed but it caused another bug in SE app for Android.

Upvotes I casted on question shown as `+2` in the app.

[image: screenshot]

In the above image, the `+2`s are upvotes I casted on questions. It is showing as my reputation earning. But it is not reflecting on profile section. So, only the achievements tab in SE for android has the issue.

Example:

- [Rewrite rule for name.123456.js in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990927/rewrite-rule-for-name-123456-js-in-htaccess/):

  - At the time of writing, the question has a total of 2 upvotes, 1 of which is mine.
  - It was certainly not due to accepted edit suggestion; there's no revision, and I already have "edit anywhere" privilege.
  - It's also not because of accepting an answer, because the question is not mine.

Comment: The -1 *was* on an answer you downvoted to the question. You didn't downvote that question.

Comment: @animuson It was my mistake. edited. There are some more issues I found with SE for Android. How I report it. I think I don't want to disturb the people by filling the home page with my posts. because they are little bugs.

Comment: @SagarV search first... there are a lot of Android bug reports here and the app hasn't been updated in a long time afaik

Comment: @Cai somewhat similar issue found on 2013 and 14. no new issues found.

Comment: Umm, is there any meta post to the "reputation system bug" that was fixed? I didn't notice any rep system bug before on SE Android app (no problem with this report, just as for documentation though). Also, I assume you're using the latest app (v1.0.89)

Comment: @AndrewT I didn't saw any meta posts. But When writing this report, the rep problem seems like fixed. The achievements tabs are updated. But now again, it is broken. And yes the app V 1.0.89